# Bluetooth property missing in Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket Class

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Bluetooth android app using monodroid v.4.0.5 and VS2010
(but the problem is the same using monodevelop).

Looking at the documentation at http://docs.monodroid.net/
it seem to be avaible the Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket Class
featuring the "IsConnected" property.
But my problem is I miss this property! (intellisense don't show it)
Can you tell me if it's the same for you?
Thanks
Federico

Answer (score 1):

The [IsConnected](http://docs.monodroid.net/?link=P%3aAndroid.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.IsConnected) property wasn't introduced until API level 14 (v4.0). In order to use the property you will need to update your project to target Android 4.0.